# Throttled async polling with Observable

Tags: c#, system.reactive, polling

Maybe I'm pushing the bounds of what is reasonable for Rx here, but what I'm trying to do is poll a remote status, but rate limit the polling to something reasonable.

Pseudo code for what I currently have:

```
IObservable<data> RemoteObservable(Remote remote) 
{
   var onceonly = Observable.FromAsyncPattern(remote.Begin, remote.End);
   return Observable.Defer(() => onceonly())
                    .ObserveOn(Scheduler.ThreadPool)
                    .Repeat();
}
```

I can't work out whether using `Throttle` or `Interval` in there might help. In my mind throttling is about limiting the incoming events, not limiting the Repeat rate.

---

**EDIT**: I asked/answered a separate question about the subquestion below: [How to make a `Defer`ed observable only subscribe for the first subscriber?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11684370/11410).

*Sub-question: is there a way to permit two subscriptions on this kind of Observable, without that creating twice as many calls to remote? I ask because I'd like to display the status continually in the UI, but also monitor it during some activities (one of the reasons I'm trying to do this with Observables).*

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
var onceOnly = Observable.FromAsyncPattern(remote.Begin, remote.End);

Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))
    .SelectMany(_ => onceOnly());
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. One question: does this start polling even before anyone's subscribed? (I'm not certain that that is something I *absolutely* have to avoid, but it's best to know for sure...)

Comment: This will not start polling until someone subscribes. If two people subscribe, you will get two timers.

Comment: OK, so that's the same (I believe) as what I'd get from `Defer`. I've just discovered [RefCount](http://nascentcode.wordpress.com/2010/12/12/creating-a-shared-refcounted-observable/), think I'll try that for size...

Answer (score 0):

For the subquestion it sounds like you could have one thing listening to that object's events (Im not familiar with Observables so not sure how that works) and then have that thing firing its own event which you could subscribe to multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to track down a similar question [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl-PL/rx/thread/52e3744e-cb18-4745-951f-51596a0f3b2d), with which an updated example of my code looks like this:

```
return Observable.Defer(() => onceonly())
                 .ObserveOn(Scheduler.ThreadPool)
                 .Concat(Observable.Empty<data>().Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)))
                 .Repeat();
```

This *appears* to work.

(However I've discovered that my `remote` object would need to be reinstantiated on every call to `FromAsyncPattern`. Not sure how I can `Repeat` that)