# How to make a `Defer`ed observable only subscribe for the first subscriber?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

Given this pseudo-code, what I'd like to do is ensure that if I have multiple subscribers, I'm not going to saturate my `remote` source with extra polling for each subscriber.

```
IObservable<data> RemoteObservable(Remote remote) 
{
   var onceonly = Observable.FromAsyncPattern(remote.Begin, remote.End);
   return Observable.Defer(() => onceonly())
                    .Repeat();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is [`RefCount`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff707550%28VS.92%29.aspx), (found [here](http://nascentcode.wordpress.com/2010/12/12/creating-a-shared-refcounted-observable/)):

```
   return Observable.Defer(() => onceonly())
                    .Repeat()
                    .Publish()
                    .RefCount();
```